# python regex re.findall taking too long to execute

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove all the words that end with a dot '.' in a file. My file is around 15 MB and would have more than 400,000 words. I am using `re.findall` to find such words and replace them.

```
for w in re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)', test_dict):
    test_dict = test_dict.replace(w, ' ')
```

This is taking very long time to execute. Is there a way to improve performance or any other alternate method to find and replace such words?

Comment: Do you pythonic method only or are you flexible with shell?

Comment: This code does not correctly implement the stated requirements, anyway.  Consider what happens if one dotted word is a suffix of another - `the.` and `lathe.` for example.  If `the.` is found first, the replacement modifies the longer word too - leaving a `la` that doesn't belong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `re.sub` instead of looping over the result of `re.findall`.

```
# Example text:
text = 'this is. a text with periods.'

re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)', ' ', text)
```

This returns the same result as your loop:

```
'this   a text with  '
```

On a relatively small document (179KB, Romeo and Juliet), the `re.findall` loop takes about 0.369 seconds, and `re.sub` takes about 0.0091 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can loop over a file line-by-line and a line word-by-word.

So you might consider:

```
with open(your_file) as f_in, open(new_file, 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
         f_out.write(' '.join(w for w in line.split() if not w.endswith('.')+'\n')
# then decide if you want to overwrite your_file with new_file
```